# Coefficient of a cubic expression $x^3-2x^2+ax+10=0$ such that sum of two roots is zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

So the given cubic is $x^3-2x^2+ax+10=0$. The condition is one of the root is additive inverse of another. I need to find the coefficient $a$. I did some algebraic calculations and cancelling of the cubic terms and square terms and got answer as $-25$. Just want to know whether its right if not then please explain me how to approach such sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The coefficient of $x^2$ is minus the sum of the three roots and you are given that two of the roots add up to zero ...

Comment: I must be stupid to have missed that ! Too old, probably ! Cheers :-(

Comment: Oh thanks general theory of equations. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

So, you face the situation $$x^3-2x^2+ax+10=(x-p)(x+p)(x+q)=0$$ Put everything on the same side, expand and simplify; this should give $$(q+2) x^2- \left(a+p^2\right)x -(p^2q+10)=0$$ Now, set each coefficient equal to zero.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: I think you have typo. $x$ is written twice  in second term

Comment: And i also dint get the reason of $(x-p)(x+p)$

Comment: additive inverse..

Comment: Does my equation translate the fact that *one of the roots is additive inverse of another* ? May be I misunderstand (English is not my language). Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

As per given condition,let $\alpha, -\alpha$ & $\beta$ be the roots of the given cubic equation: $x^3-2x^2+ax+10=0$ then the sum of roots $$\alpha+(-\alpha)+\beta=-\frac{\text{coefficient of}  \ x^2}{\text{coefficient of}  \ x^3}$$$$\beta=-\frac{(-2)}{1}=2$$
now, substituting $\beta=2$ in the cubic equation, one should get 
$$(2)^3-2(2)^2+a(2)+10=0$$ 
$$2a+10=0$$$$\implies a=\color{red}{-5}$$